# Select base class in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Suppose I have

```
table Person
table Employee, which inherits Person.
```

I want to get a list of Person, regardless if this Person is Employee or not. How do you get entity framework to do that *without* joining the Employee table? C# is what I'm using. Thanks.

Comment: I take it you mean you only want the values in Person that are not in Employee?

Also, what language, libraries, etc?

Comment: Thanks I should have been more clear. I want to retrieve Person properties for every row of Person. What I don't want is entity framework doing the "left outer join [Employee]" in its generated sql. I'm using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you don't implicitly use any information from `Employee`.

If you do this:

```
var people = Context.People.ToList();
```

... Then me Entity Framework will initialize new instances of type `Employee` for those people who happen to be employees. This is because when you store an `Employee` in the database, you generally expect to get an `Employee` back when you select the same item.

Nor, for that matter, can you tell the Entity Framework to give you a `Person` when the stored value is an `Employee`. The Entity Framework will never give you back an incorrect entity type.

However, if you do just want to read the one table, there is a way to do that: Select the data from `Person` into a non-entity types, such as an anonymous type:

```
var people = Context.People.Select(p => new { Name = p.Name }).ToList();
```